# decrease in unit test success in sonar

Tags: unit-testing, maven, code-coverage, sonarqube

Recently i have upgraded sonar from 3.1.1 to 3.2.1. There is a decrease in unit test success leading to decrease in code coverage. In 3.1.1 there were no errors after unit test and 100%unit test success, but in 3.2.1 about 267 errors generated after test resulting 93% unit test success.
could someone tell me what to do to get 100%success in unit test?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Make the tests pass?

Comment: previously they got passed but now they are getting failed. I want to know y this happens

Comment: Read the test results, the stack traces, etc. Day to day developer job.